# Good-looking buttons (using CSS) on Internet Explorer

Tags: css

Let's face it, regular Input form buttons are boring and plain. So I tried searching and I thought.. maybe you guys know a better answer.

Do you guys know where I could find sexy css form buttons that work on Internet Explorer?

Thanks

Comment: I have some I made but am away from the office for a couple of days. I'll try to remember to post it for you.

Comment: Let's face it, IE is boring and plain. IE users are used to it. ;)

Comment: When developing for IE I try to keep everything boring as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI CSS has some really nice looking ones (I think):

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/buttonFrameworkCSS/

(edited link)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I recommand you [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).

It is a HTML/CSS framework which allows you make [great buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) (among others) easily.

This buttons are **"crossbrowser"** which means they are **compatible with Internet Explorer**.

With only one class - `btn` - you can stylize a `<button>`, `<input type="button">` or `<a>`.

This :

```
<button class="btn"></button>
```

Gives that:

[image]

You also can customize your button quickly with an optional class :

`btn-primary`, `btn-info`, `btn-success`, `btn-warning`, `btn-danger` and `btn-inverse`.

This classes transform your button like that :

[image]

Then you can choose a size with the classes `btn-large`, `btn-small` and `btn-mini`.

Finally, you can add an icon ([the list is here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons)) in your button.

This:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>
    <span>Checkout</span>
</button>
```

Gives that:

[image]

Have fun with your new buttons. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the background-image property of CSS to change the way your input buttons are rendered. You may set a fixed pixel width and height and create a background graphic with a program like Photoshop or Gimp. If you need the button label to be dynamic then make the image without the text label. This method is not as flexible as other methods but it does guarantee that your buttons will look the same in IE, FireFox and pretty much every other browser. Here is a example CSS class to apply to your input buttons that uses the 'sliding door' method to let you give your button a hover highlight:

```
.my-styled-button {
  background-image: url('images/my-button-background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
}
.my-styled-button:hover {
  background-position: 0px -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://github.com/imathis/fancy-buttons

Comment: I downloaded it and went to on my Chrome.. it seems broken.

Comment: yea, the git hub download is a piece. I can host the pictures if you want them. Just comment and I will.